# Quadratic equations greater than zero, then we have at most one real root

Tags: general-topology, quadratics

I'm watching [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Lzm8TgePzzg&index=2&list=PLwvHeFZqWPaHtgocYudUsWObfsOp0VNt2) on what's a metric (in topology), specifically I'm at the 5th minute, where the interlocutor says that *quadratic equations greater than zero have at most one real root, because it touches zero only once*. Specifically, the equation is talking about is $$f(t) = \sum_{i=1}^n (a_i + tb_i)^2 \geq 0$$

I'm aware of when the discriminant of the quadratic formula is negative, $0$ or positive we have respectively no, one and $2$ solutions (because of obvious reasons from arithmetic), but I'm not really getting the statement above.

Maybe it's an easy thing and I'm simply not currently seeing it...

Answer (score 1):

$x^2$ for any $x \in \Bbb{R}$ is $0$ if and only if $x=0$. All other times, they are positive. Thus, summing $(a_i+b_i\cdot t)^2$ is summing a bunch of non-negative expressions and that sum can only be $0$ when all of them are zero: That is, they can only be zero when all of the $a_i+b_i\cdot t=0$, which can happen at most for one value of $t$.

For example, the following has one solution:
$$(t+2)^2 = 0$$
The above is only true when $t=-2$ since that's when $t+2=0$. All other times, the left-hand side is positive. Here, the discriminant is $0$.

Also, the following has no solution:
$$(t+2)^2+(3t+1)^2=0$$
This has no solutions because for the first term to be $0$, we need $t=-2$, but for the second term to be $0$, we need $t=-\frac{1}{3}$, meaning that both can not be $0$ at the same time, so the left-hand side is always positive. Here, the discriminant is $-100$.

Finally, the following has one solution:
$$(t+2)^2+(2t+4)^2=0$$
The first term is $0$ when $t+2=0 \implies t=-2$ and the second term is also $0$ when $2t+4=0 \implies t=-2$, so we get that there is one solution of $t=-2$ and for all other $t$, the left-hand side is positive. Here, the discriminant is $0$.

Answer (score 0):

Since we are talking about *real* (and not complex) quantities, every square is $\ge 0$. Furthermore, if $f(t) = 0$ then all the squares inside $f$ must be $0$, i.e. $(a_i + t b_i)^2 = 0$ for all $i$, meaning that $a_i + t b_i = 0$ for all $i$. This implies $t = - \frac {a_i} {b_i}$ for all $i$. Letting $k$ be the common value of all these fractions, we get $a_i = k b_i$ for all $i$ so $f$ looks like $\sum_i (k b_i + t b_i)^2 = (k+t)^2 \sum_i b_i^2$.

To conclude, either $f$ has no root, or if it has, then $f$ must have the very peculiar form shown above and the root is unique (well, if you really want to be strict, then the root has multiplicity $2$).